# Warning message: In data(xx) : data set ‘xx’ not found

Tags: r

Keep getting the following warning:

> "Warning message:
>   In data(VEMCOdata) : data set ‘VEMCOdata’ not found"

I'm new to R. I set up all my files exactly how the package VTrack specified. I set my working directory, load my first data set then ue the command >data(xx) and keep getting the same warning message.

```
setwd("C:/Users/gwhite/Desktop")
 library(VTrack)
 VEMCOdata <- read.csv('VEMCOdata_2014.csv')
 data(VEMCOdata)
```

> Warning message:
>   In data(VEMCOdata) : data set ‘VEMCOdata’ not found

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data with `dput(head(df,n))` and the output of `getwd()`. We have no access to your computer. What does this return? `'VEMCOdata_2014.csv' %in% list.files()`?

Comment: I don't understand why you need the ```data``` function : if you want to see the data frame, just write ```View(VEMCOdata)```. Maybe you should convert the csv file in a data frame with ````VEMCOdata <- as.data.frame(VEMCOdata)````

Comment: `data(VEMCOdata)` only needs to be included if you want to use the author's example data. To view your VEMCOdata use `head(VEMCOdata)`